# .NET Core 2.2. How do I get rid of this HTTP 405 error when trying to delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm getting a 405 error when trying to do a simple post with a delete. I can read, write, and update just fine, but cannot figure out why Visual Studio 2017 (or, maybe more specifically, IIS Express) won't let me perform a delete.

The internet has a lot of posts regarding `web.config`, but they're older posts and the more recent one's don't work. In fact, there was no `web.config` included in my project because Microsoft is moving towards `appsettings.json`, I believe.

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.11 with .NET Core 2.2 in a Docker container. I switched to IIS Express with no luck. I've looked at the `applicationhost.config` file for IIS Express and WebDav is commented out already. I believe it's happening at the web server level because I'm not getting a hit on the controller when debugging. My best guess is there's a default setting somewhere that's not allowing deletes; I just can't find it.

#### Model

```cs
namespace Efficacy.Models.Entities
{
    /* dbo.Contact.Contact */
    public class Contact
    {
        private const string V = "First Name";

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ContactType ContactType { get; set; }
        public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //[Display( Description = ("Delete")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### DBContext

```cs
namespace Efficacy.Data
{
    public class EfficacyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; protected set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContactType> ContactType { get; protected set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HelloNurse> HelloNurse { get; protected set; }

        public EfficacyDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactEntityTypeConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```cs
namespace Efficacy.Areas.Ops.Controllers
{
    [Area("Ops")]
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EfficacyDBContext _db;

        public ContactController(EfficacyDBContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ContactDelete(int id)
        {
            var contact = await _db.Contact.FindAsync(id);

            if (contact == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _db.Contact.Remove(contact);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
…
```

#### View

```
@model Efficacy.Models.Entities.Contact
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Contact";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-info">Add Contact</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            &nbsp
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form method="post" asp-area="Ops" asp-controller="Contact"  
                asp-action="ContactDelete">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <table class="table table-striped border shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th><label asp-for="FirstName">First Name</label></th>
                    <th><label asp-for="MiddleName">Middle</label></th>
                    <th><label asp-for="LastName">Last Name</label></th>
                    <th><label asp-for="ContactTypeId">Contact Type</label></th>
                    <th class="text-right">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control"
                               value="@Model.FirstName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"
                              class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control"
                               value="@Model.MiddleName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"
                              class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control"
                               value="@Model.LastName" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"
                              class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @* TODO:  Bind *@
                        <select name="ContactTypeId" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Organization</option>
                            <option value="2">Lead</option>
                            <option value="3">Event</option>
                            <option value="4">Invoice</option>
                            <option value="5">Contact</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control mb-1"
                               asp-route-id="@Model.Id" value="Save" />
                        <a asp-area="ops" asp-controller="Contact"
                           asp-action="ContactDelete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"
                           class="btn btn-danger form-control mb-1">Delete</a>
                        <a asp-action="Index"
                           class="btn btn-success form-control">Cancel</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Console Output

```sh
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44382/Ops/Contact/ContactDelete/11  
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44382/Ops/Contact/ContactDelete/11  
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 14.0081ms 405
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area=Ops}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Do you have the anti forgery token included in your call?

Comment: are you using `HTTP` `DELETE` from client side?

Comment: @Tachyon I looked into this, but MS says that for core 2.0 and above a token is automatically generated when there's a 'method="post"'. [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2 [link] I confirmed the token in the source.

Comment: @aarif The call is being rendered as a form post from the view (No Javascript)

Answer (score 6):

`405` HTTP code means `Method Not Allowed`. Served returned this error because action expects `POST` request (since it's marked with `[HttpPost]`) and when user click on anchor tag (`<a>`) browser sends `GET` request. In order to send `POST` you need to use `form` tag

```html
<form method="post" asp-action="ContactDelete" asp-area="Ops" asp-controller="Contact">
    <input name="Id" value="@item.Id" type="hidden" /> <!-- hidden input contains Id value -->
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Also you have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on the action so it needs anti-forgery token to be sent. [FormTagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2) will automatically generate hidden `input` with this token for you so you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: I checked my source and there is an anti-forgery token there.  I didn't think I needed a Taghelper on the Razor page view because MS Says:  The automatic generation of antiforgery tokens for HTML form elements happens when the <form> tag contains the method="post".   Do you perhaps have a little code snippet from a view you can share with me?  So far I've tried `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I am including a form tag.  My bad.  I was just trying to keep my post short.  Here's the tag I'm using:  `<form method="post" asp-area="ops" asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="ContactDelete">`

Comment: I've included my complete view in the source.

Comment: @Alexamder You were right.  After reviewing the headers I saw that it was a 405 GET request due to the fact I was using `<a asp-area="ops" asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="ContactDelete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"
                           class="btn btn-danger form-control mb-1">Delete</a>` ...Instead of an input post element.  DUH.  Forms 101.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

i believe your issue is routing problem
can you try this.

```
    [HttpPost("id")] <----------
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactDelete([FromRoute(Name = "id" )] int id) <----------
    {
        var contact = await _db.Contact.FindAsync(id);

        if (contact == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _db.Contact.Remove(contact);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use POST method,it's better to include "id" in hidden element in form scope and send it with other values:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
```

I see you are trying to update and delete the same form.then you should use two Submit buttons with different Actions

```
<button type="submit" asp-action="Save" asp-controller="Contact" asp-area="Ops" class="btn  form-control">
  <span>Update</span>
</button> 

<button type="submit" asp-action="ContactDelete" asp-controller="Contact" asp-area="Ops" class="btn form-control">
  <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

one more thing... remove Controller,Action and Area tags in form element and let submit buttons handle that:

```
  <form asp-action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```